# Import Only recently added CSV Files to SQL Server from a Folder

Tags: sql-server, csv, import

I use this following query to have a list of all csv files I want to import in a SQL SERVER table. Now I wonder if there's a way to add a column in my table ALLFILENAMES with the Last Modified Date of the CSV file so I update only the most recent ones?:

`SET @path = 'C:\temp\'
    SET @cmd = 'dir ' + @path + '*.csv /b'
    INSERT INTO  ALLFILENAMES(WHICHFILE)
    EXEC Master..xp_cmdShell @cmd
    UPDATE ALLFILENAMES SET WHICHPATH = @path where WHICHPATH is null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by using a different parameter (/tw) to Master..xp_cmdShell. That gives me a string with the date and the name of the file. I make 2 fields out of them in a table and then I run BULK INSERT and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSIS for this. Watch this video of [SSIS Interview Question - How to load most recent file from Folder to Table in SSIS Package](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Q32tD-I1EI)

**UPDATE:** If you want code click [here](http://www.techbrothersit.com/2013/12/ssis-how-to-get-most-recent-file-from.html)

Comment: thank you for your help although this solution is in Visual Studio, I'm using SQL Server Management Studio so I'm hoping for a SQL query. Also, I have about 25,000 files which about 250 are new every day so they will have today's date and would need to update the table with those new files.